# How remove "installed twice" errors in RCP Product

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP product based on 2 features: my product feature and the org.eclipse.rcp feature. It worked perfectly at export time and at run time.

Last week I decided to add the error log view to my product. I simply added the view to my "persective" and the logview plugin as plugin dependency in my main plugin. Just work fine !!!

After exporting my product (through headless build) I noticed that when launching my product I have a lot of errors in the error log view (not acceptable for customers even if all is working fine). These errors are related to the RCP feature plugins and say:

the plugin org.eclipse.xxx (one error for each plugin of the RCP feature) has already been installed from /plugins/org.eclipse.xxx

Any idea on the way to avoid these errors ? I guess this means I have something wrong in my product configuration.

Comment: how about check the .log file after exporting your product? Maybe it's generated when exporting your product by PDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to add the following line in the product config.ini file:

```
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
```